# Media Query not picking up

Tags: css, media-queries

I was trying to change a div's width on mobile phone. Here is my css code for media query

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 414px) 
  and (max-device-width: 736px) 
 { 

         .login-page{
        width: :80% !important;;
        padding: 8% 0 0 !important;;
        margin: auto;
      }  

      body{
        background-color: red;
      }

}
```

I have included the following lines on my php header file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 713px)" href="css/media.css" />
```

What's wrong with my approach?

Comment: Thanks, removed the tag

Comment: please check the answer that I posted if it solves your issue. @arun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change you `@media` as all things should appear in one line like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-width: 736px)
```

**OR you can also try with this :**

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 414px) and (max-width: 736px)
 { 

     .login-page{
    width: :80% !important;;
    padding: 8% 0 0 !important;;
    margin: auto;
  }  

  body{
    background-color: red;
  }
```

}

Also remove media from this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 713px)" href="css/media.css" />
```

to :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this - after hours of searching - by clearing the cache *on the phone*...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change you `@media` to this

```
@media all and (min-width: 414px) and (max-width: 736px) 
 { 

         .login-page{
        width: :80% !important;;
        padding: 8% 0 0 !important;;
        margin: auto;
      }  

      body{
        background-color: red;
      }

}
```

Comment: Tried my code with the changes you have mentioned. Still It's not picking up the media query :(

Comment: could you please share anything a link or a fiddle??